# SDL and Visual Studio 2010 resources

Tags: c++, resources, sdl

I have a simple question. I use SDL and SDL_image in my c++ program and image loading is fine from a single png file.

```
SDL_Surface *dot = NULL;
dot = load_image("dot.png");
```

But how can I load the png file if I add it to the resources? so I don't want to store in a png file next to the exe. Is it possible to load from the resources?

Tried

```
dot = load_image(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_PNG1));
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

It is fully possible to load an image or something else into SDL from a windows resource. To do this you need to get the raw data and pass it to the appropriate RWOPS.

```
HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(_T("myapp.exe"));

HRSRC hWhite = FindResource(hModule, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_WHITE_PNG), _T("PNG"));            
unsigned int white_size = SizeofResource(hModule, hWhite);
HGLOBAL hgWhite = LoadResource(hModule, hWhite);
unsigned char* white_data = (unsigned char*)LockResource(hgWhite);

SDL_Surface* white = IMG_Load_RW(SDL_RWFromConstMem(white_data, white_size), 1);
```

This assumes that you have something similar in your *.rc file:

```
IDB_WHITE_PNG  PNG "White.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the `MAKEINTRESOURCE` [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648029%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) :

> The return value should be passed only to functions which explicitly indicate that they accept MAKEINTRESOURCE as a parameter.

You don't give the content of `load_image` (BTW, please include the content of the functions you use in your question, you'll get better answers ...) but I bet it's not using its parameter to call one of the Windows SDK functions which accept `MAKEINTRESOURCE` ... as far as I know these resources are supposed to hold some specific Windows UI data like mouse cursors, icons, etc.. for use with Windows functions, not with other libraries like SDL, so I'm not surprised it doesn't work.